# Vim echo or echomsg without newline

Tags: vim

Is there a way to `echo` or `echomsg` a message in vim without the automatically inserted newline character?
I have tried using the backspace character `\b` to erase the newline after the echo, without luck.

```
echo "foo"
echo "\b \b"
echo "bar"
"long list of such words to echo
```

I need to display this as `foobar`. Currently it displays each echo message on a new line.

> foo
>
> bar

I could buffer the echos, but I want to avoiding buffering, as there may be a delay in between the echos, ie:- I want to display the progress. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `echon` which will add nothing to the output.

```
echon 'foo'
echon 'bar'
```

output:

```
foobar
```

Take a look at [`:h echon`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#%3aechon)

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. I think @roland and your answers crossed midair!

Comment: Just a little note, as I understand it `echon` is not __prepending__ a new line, I think no one of the `echo...` commands __appends__ a new line, there is no need for it. So above can be written as `echo "foo" | echon "bar"`. Perhaps it doesn't mean so much but can be good to know

Answer (score 2):

Use `echon`:

```
echon "foo"
echon "\b \b"
echon "bar"
```

Comment: Is the middle line necessary?